# File upload on iphone doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I'm trying to use file input on iPhone in Safari, and it doesn't work. It is either don't work at all, or starting the camera (not allowing to upload a file from gallery). I've heard that is a known problem for old Safari, but this doesn't work on new iPhones too. Tested on iPhone 4 and iPhone 6s. Also it works on Windows (all modern browsers) and Android (Chrome on Android 6.0.1).

I'm using html input type="file" wrapped inside label. Click on that label activates the input. Any thoughts, what it can be and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally you would have an `<input type="file">` element and listen to its `change` event. Never had any issue with that on iOS. But do post your code so people can have a look at it.

Comment: I am having this problem after the latest iOS update (10.3.1) on an ipad pro. It used to work, now it goes straight to the camera with no way to switch to gallery. Something probably changed in the new Safari